# Error trying to establish connection to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, go, runtime-error

I am trying to establish a connection to the SQL Server database, for that I am using the module https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb, but when creating the connection string with the database it generates a error which says

> InitialBytes InitializeSecurityContext failed 8009030c.

My code:

```
const (
    server   = "NIX"
    user     = "user"
    password = ""
    database = "Activity_Control"
)

func Connection() *sql.DB {
    connString := fmt.Sprintf("server=%s;user id=%s;password=%s;database=%s;", server, user, password, database)

    db, err := sql.Open("sqlserver", connString)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
        return db
    }

    ctx := context.Background()

    err = db.PingContext(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
        return db
    }

    return db
}
```

Comment: _InitializeSecurityContext failed 8009030c_ ... is the server configured to accept SQL Login authentication? It might be expecting domain/Windows authentication.

Comment: Further to this comment - what happens when you try to connect to SQL Server using those values from a tool like SSMS or Azure Data Studio? You may get a more enlightening error message